# Upgrading be_acl to TYPO3 v7

Tags: typo3

Does any one have an experience upgrading be_acl from 1.5.0 to 3.0.0 for TYPO3 v7.6.4?

What difficulties did you encounter and how did you solve it?

Lastly any alternative you can recommend? Perhaps projects not yet in TER? A search for "permissions" or "access control" in TER does not yield relevant results.

Thanks,
Alvin